# Flask SqlAlchemy Id uuid primary key wrong format

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, uuid

In my flask rest api app I have this model about user registration:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from db import db
import uuid

class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    created = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    uuid_user = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False)
    activated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

So for id primary key I set a uuid key.
Into DB the value is inserted with correctly format, example:

```
465dc674-ca3a-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002
```

Now I have this function to retrieve all user for db:

```
@blp.route("/v0/user/<int:id>")
class User(MethodView):
    @blp.response(200, UserSchema)
    def get(self, id):
        user = UserModel.query.get_or_404(id)
        return user
```

and when I run get request with Postam, the value of id into response is like this:

```
"activated": false,
        "created": "03/24/2023, 11:29:40",
        "email": "<mail>@gmail.com",
        "id": 2.89867639142417965323251007576809137908e+38,
```

and this is the userschema:

```
class UserSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    username = fields.Str(required=True)
    password = fields.Str(required=True)
    email = fields.Str(required=True)
    created = fields.Str(required=False)
    uuid_user = fields.Str(required=False)
    activated = fields.Bool(required=False)
```

How can I retrive the id with correct uuid format into db and use it for delete or get/id ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share `UserSchema`? Furthermore why do you use integer in the route definition `<int:id>` when `id` is an uuid4?

Comment: Hello Dauros, i have edit my original post with user schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of `id` field in the schema from integer to UUID:

```
class UserSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.UUID(dump_only=True)
    username = fields.Str(required=True)
    password = fields.Str(required=True)
    email = fields.Str(required=True)
    created = fields.Str(required=False)
    uuid_user = fields.Str(required=False)
    activated = fields.Bool(required=False)
```

Furthermore change the type of the route parameter as well to avoid unnecessary converting:

```
@blp.route("/v0/user/<uuid:id>")
class User(MethodView):
    ...
```